How to use msvc ASan for Cpp extension of python?
I wish to use ASan on msvc for cpp extensions of python. I'm on win10 and VS2022 17.9.3. Frist I tried microsoft's tutorial and it works. Then I use cython to wrap my cpp code. My code is here.
When I use ubuntu, I can run my code well after export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/{your gcc version}/libasan.so. But on windows, it says "ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cydbg_cy: The specified module could not be found". I think it raises because it couldn't find ASan's location, just as I need to export LD_PRELOAD on linux. But I don't know where it is. Any advice would be appreciated!

Update
I add
import os
if os.name == "nt":
    os.add_dll_directory(r'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\bin\Hostx64\x64')

in main.py before from cydbg.cython import cydbg_cy, and run pdm main, now it works. However, when I use linux(wsl2), the error hints would be detailed, e.g.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free /mnt/c/Codes/cydbg/src/cydbg/cpp/src/cpp.cpp:17 in CppClass::use_after_free()

But on windows, it would be
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free (C:\Codes\cydbg\src\cydbg\cython\cydbg_cy.cp310-win_amd64.pyd+0x180005378)

This hint is not that helpful as hint on linux. How to change it?
